# get Picture from exising camera app Windows Phone 8.1 runtime c#

Tags: c#, camera, runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I would like to call a function, the Standard camera-app of the Phone opens, the user takes a photo and i'll get some informations about tzhe photo taken.

I DON'T want so write a seperate photo-app (well i have to do it in another view with Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCapture, where i want to read Barcodes, but here i just want to get a nice photo)

in my opinion it should work like the SpeechRecognizer, i just wait until ist finished and i have a result.

Is there a way to do it or I am forced to write my own camera-view? (It would be nice if the user would have a common look and feel of a camera on his Phone)

anybody knows if it's possible and how?

regands
mech

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Phone 7 and 8 you could use PhotoChooserTask but it is not longer available in Windows Phone 8.1 XAML. But there is a workaround for this.

You can use the FileOpenPicker

```
var picker = new  FileOpenPicker
{
    ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail,
    SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary, 
};

picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");

picker.PickSingleFileAndContinue();
```

This will start a picker to choose a photo rom the pictures library but there is a camera button in the bottom of the UI that the user can use to take a new picture.

Comment: that could be an alternative, but a direct way would be better. I would also like to store the Pictures in Appdata, not in picturesLibrary (Pictures will be stored in subfolders regarding a specific item, later on they will be uploaded and deleted))

Comment: I am afraid this is the best you can do now